# How to integrate InMobi ad in ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, inmobi

I tried to integrate InMobi ad with phonegap plugin but got error. How to integrate **InMobi ad** in ionic? Is there any plugin for it?

Comment: Hey Manish. I work at InMobi. What error did you see? Can you give some sample code please?

Comment: @Sohan Thanks for reply. Can you please give me steps to integrate InMobi ad in ionic. Actually i didn't get any InMobi ad plugin for ionic.

Comment: Hey Manish. Sorry but we don't have a plugin for Ionic specifically. Best you can do is the phoneGap plugin since they're both JS based.

Comment: @Sohan Thanks. Can you please provide me correct phoneGap plugin link for InMobi ad and steps to integrate into ionic?

Comment: @Sohan I can't get ads to show in my ionic-based app. I tried following the code in the answer below as well as digging through the integration tutorial in inMobi website. However what I get is an error from inMobi with code === "nfr". Is there any way I can reach you privately or through inMobi support?

Answer (score 0):

You can integration javascript API (mobile web). follow steps below.

1. To Get property id create an Inmobi account at Inmobi Site.
2. After succesfully created an Inmobi account, log in to your Inmobi account. In the menu bar, select MONETIZE and fill in the necessary information. There are 4 types of property: Windows Phone, iOS, Android and Mobile Web. In this sample, we choose the Mobile Web. Then, click on Add Property button.
3. Next, you need to verify the newly created property which is required by Inmobi. In the property list, click on the Verification button.

To complete the verification, please add the following meta tag within the HTML head tag of your property URL.

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="inmobi-site-verification" content="4028cba631d63df10131e1d3191d00cb"> //replace your property ID here
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

4. Include inmobi.js
5. Use below code for inmobi preference settings

   `var inmobi_conf =
     {
       siteid : "4028cba631d63df10131e1d3191d00cb", // your Property ID
       slot: 15,
       test: true,
       manual: true,
       autoRefresh: 60,
       targetWindow : "_blank", // default "_top"
       onError : function(code)
       {
         if(code == "nfr")
         {
           console.log("Error getting the ads!");
         }
       }
     };`
6. Add div for rendering ads and onDeviceReady() call function **showAds()**

   `function showAds()
     {
       var adsElement = document.getElementById('ads');
       _inmobi.getNewAd(adsElement);
     }`

Comment: I am always receiving an error back from the server: the callback onError is always called with the code === "nfr", and I can't manage to get an ad to be displayed. I added a test device from inMobi dashboard and passed its hash in inmobi_conf object, but I still can't manage to get an (test) ad from inMobi.

Comment: @user1068051 - First you have to verify your website by using metatag in head tag. Metatag content would be your propertyID.

Comment: I already added that tag, I copied your code as it is, replacing siteid and device test id. I cannot start the verification from inmobi dashboard, I asked their support but it seems like I cannot verify my app from the dashboard since I haven't yet published it on any store

Comment: Hey. Sohan from InMobi here. Have you checked the box that says your app isn't live and is a test app? You will also have to enter the device ID of the test ID in your dashboard.

Comment: @user1068051, Even if you're creating an Android or iOS app, choose mobile web in the InMobi dashboard as you are using the JS plugin. You should start seeing ads then.

Comment: @RaviMishra - Thanks for the answer. it's working good for me.

Comment: @RaviMishra, I'm missing this step 4 ( Include inmobi.js ) part. Where can I get the js library file? And is this code working for Native Ads?

Comment: @SATISH, you can get js file here http://cf.cdn.inmobi.com/ad/inmobi.js

Comment: @SATISH, Please refer this link for more detail. https://support.inmobi.com/monetize/integration/mobile-web/